# Why is font-weight by hundreds when the only available values are multiples of 100?

Tags: css

The question has bothered me for a while.

In CSS, the font-weight can only be a value that is a multiple of 100, from 100 to 900

Example : https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Open+Sans

So why it is so? What is the origin that its reffered as 100, 200, 300... etc. instead of, for instance, 1,2,3, etc?

Comment: Why? I don't know. That's it. But you can read W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight

Comment: A curious question: how does it matters, if it's 100 by 100 or 1 by 1? What change in your development?

Comment: I'm confused. How is this a question for Super User? This is a question about the CSS font-weight property. It's not a question about typography in general (which wouldn't be on-topic on SU, either).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it derives from the Linotype typeface classification system ([Linotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univers#Linotype_numbering_system)).
Where a 3-number system is used, first numeral describes font weight, second numeral describes font width, third numeral describes position.

There's an interesting article [here](http://bigelowandholmes.typepad.com/bigelow-holmes/2015/07/on-font-weight.html) on some of the history of specifying font weights in print.